# How to avoid create multi new function in map iterative block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

for example, I have code below, because my onPressCover need params of ele.id, ele.uri, ele.title , so I only know this only way to do this needs now, but it seems like create a side effect of creating new function of each TouchableOpacity, so is there any other good way which can get the need also avoid the side effect?

```
onPressCover = (id,uri,title) => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Introduce',{ 
    id: id, 
    uri: uri,
    title: title, 
    author: '', 
    description: ''
  }) 
}

this.stuff.map((ele,index) => (
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.cover} key={index} onPress={() => { this.onPressStuff(ele.id,ele.uri,ele.title) }}>
    <Text numberOfLines={2} style={styles.coverText}>{ele.title}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity> )
```

Comment: Why it is considered as a  side effect ? . By all means, we are not doing anything in onpress function. just passing it to onPressCover. OnPressCover will be same for all the mapped elements. As per my knowledge, we don't have any other way. May be more people can provide any insights into it

Comment: Problem is here if you are using this map in your render (most probably yes) then in every render this function is also being created. This causes or might cause performance issues. Instead of doing this, you can pass the `el` to your TouchableOpacity component and give your onPressCover as a reference prop. In your component using a handlePress function you can invoke your onPressCover prop function.

Comment: I don't know React Native so much but I see now TouchableOpacity is a React component. So in order to do what I suggest here you need to create a separate component. I will try to drop an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your function to be re-created for every render you can create a separate component for TouchableOpacity and use a calback logic there.

```
this.stuff.map( ele =>
  <MyTouchableOpacity key={ele.id} ele={ele} onPress={this.onPressCover} /> )
```

Then in your MyTouchableOpacity component:

```
const MyTouchableOpacity = ( { ele, onPress } ) => {
    const handlePress => onPress( ele.id, ele.uri, ele.title );
    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.cover} onPress={handlePress}>
                <Text numberOfLines={2} style={styles.coverText}>{ele.title}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: I think this is a enough good way until another better answer appear